# What does "this dropped" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I see a comment on YouTube says:

> This dropped as I was studying maths

It's about a YouTuber says she doesn't like math. So what does this sentence mean?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the full dialog, an HTML link to the discussion, or a screenshot of the dialog. The meaning is unclear from the quote you've given.

Comment: Could you please provide the link to the actual video? You've gotten me curious.

Comment: It's not possible to tell which of the provided answers is actually correct in this case because there isn't enough context in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression **This/it/something dropped** is most frequently used in two contexts.

The first is to say that **I suddenly understood** or **had a flash of inspiration**. The usual expression is that **the penny dropped**, arising from the use of coin machines where the dropping of a coin produces a product or result. A similar expression is **the light dawned**.

**This/it/something dropped** is also used to describe mail or packages that are thrust through the aperture in many front doors intended for mail (and known by sundry names including letter box, letter plate, letter hole, mail slot or mailbox).

The expression may refer to one or other although it's impossible to say without further context.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+penny+drops
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_box
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(United_States_coin)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(British_decimal_coin)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for no enough context...

Answer (score 3):

*Dropped* here means *was published*. So, the video was published while the commenter was studying math.

This is the relevant definition in [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Drop):

> The availability of a product or service to the general public. The term is most often used in relation to the release of a music album, a DVD video release, or hardware or software, but can be used for other products (i.e., concert tickets.)
>
> > Windows 7 is slated to drop on October 22nd
> >
> > The new iPods dropped last week.

This slang has been in use for quite some time, specifically when referring to music being released. According to the OED in this sense it dates back to 1988.